# Add a button (or any control really) to a listbox in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know this probably simple, but I have been searching google, and I really haven't made much ground.

I would like to take a button for example, and add it to a listbox, programatically, not in the xaml.

My current stategy for doing this is :

```
Button testButton = new Button();
listbox.Items.add(testButton);
```

Comment: So what is the issue, doesn't it show your Button ?

Comment: Set Content property of the Button.

Comment: To downvoter, why?  The user is having trouble doing something, tried some code, searched for answers, and came here for help.  Sometimes it's really hard to find very simple solutions online because most forum questions are about specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this...

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "myitem";
        b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
        listBox1.Items.Add(b);
    }

    void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item CLicked");
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, the button is not shown in the listbox

Answer (score 1):

ListBox has an Items collection property that you can add any control into it.

```
var listBox = new ListBox();
var button = new Button()
                        {
                         Content = "Click me"
                        };
var textBlock = new TextBlock()
                        {
                         Text = "This is a textblock"
                        };
 listBox.Items.Add(button);
 listBox.Items.Add(textBlock);
```

Add method is expecting an object type so it can take data types like strings, integer, classes that you want to show in the list.